# Separating single file into different files with respect to particular string

Tags: text-processing, sed, solaris

I have one file with following entries

```
vdomain
v2host
v3server
v1adapter
vhost
v2domain
v1application
```

I want to separate all these entries into 4 different files like

file1 : should contain names starting with "v"

```
vdomain
vhost
```

file2 : should contain names starting with "v1"

```
v1application
v1adapter
```

file3 : should contain names starting with "v2"

```
v2host
v2domain
```

file4 : should contain names starting with "V3"

```
v3server
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^v[^123]/ { print >"file1" }
     /^v1/ { print >"file2" }
     /^v2/ { print >"file3" }
     /^v3/ { print >"file4" }' inputfile
```

This will create your four files.

The first regular expression matches only lines starting with a `v` not followed by the digits 1, 2 or 3 (since these are to go in the other files).  Lines not matching any of the regular expressions are discarded.

The equivalent thing with `sed`:

```
sed -n \
    -e '/^v[^123]/w file1' \
    -e '/^v1/w file2' \
    -e '/^v2/w file3' \
    -e '/^v3/w file4' inputfile
```

The `w` command in `sed` writes the current line to the named file.

And with a shell loop (you don't *really* want to use this):

```
rm -f file[1234]
while read -r words; do
    case "$words" in
        v1*) printf '%s\n' "$words" >>file2 ;;
        v2*) printf '%s\n' "$words" >>file3 ;;
        v3*) printf '%s\n' "$words" >>file4 ;;
        v*)  printf '%s\n' "$words" >>file1 ;;
    esac
done <inputfile
```

This is *almost* the same except that whitespaces after each input line will be removed, also initial whitespaces are ignored and dropped. Here, the order of the tests is also important.

And finally, with `ed`, with a script that is, unsurprisingly, identical to the one used with `sed`:

```
cat <<ED_END | ed -s inputfile
/^v[^123]/w file1
/^v1/w file2
/^v2/w file3
/^v3/w file4
ED_END
```